# Integrating a function with 3 branch points: $\int_{C} z^{a-1} (z+z^{-1})^{b} \, \mathrm dz $

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I came across an exercise in a textbook that says to evaluate $$ \int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos (ax) \cos^{b} (x) \, dx  \, , \quad a > b > -1,$$ by integrating $f(z) = z^{a-1} (z+z^{-1})^{b}$  around a contour that consists of the line segment joining the points $i$ and $-i$, along with the right half of the unit circle.

It also says that the contour should be indented at the points $0, i$, and $-i$.

But where should the branch cuts be placed?  Can we just use the principal branch of the logarithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All that's happening is that you are avoiding the branch points with your contour so you can apply Cauchy's theorem.  You have branch points where the argument any non-integral power is zero, in your case, at $z=0$ and $\pm i$.

Cauchy's theorem states that

$$\oint_C dz \: f(z)=0$$

So the original integral is going to equal the integral along the line joining $i$ to $-i$ plus any contribution from the indentations, if any.  Is there any?  Let's take the one at $z=i$  Let $z=i + \epsilon e^{i \phi}$ and the contribution is

$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\: i \epsilon^{1+b} \int_0^{-\pi/2} d \phi \: e^{i (a+b) \phi}$$

This is zero because $-1>b$. (Whew!)  Same for the other branch point at $z=-i$.

At $z=0$, we let $z= \epsilon e^{i \phi}$, and we will see that this contribution goes to zero because $a>b$.

So the integral you seek is simply the real part of the  integral of $f(z)$ along the straight line from $i$ to $-i$.

Comment: So there is a branch cut from $i$ to $i \infty$, a branch cut along the negative imaginary axis, and a branch cut from $-i$ to $-i \infty$? And you're never crossing over any of them?

Comment: @Random: we avoid crossing any cuts because the contour is indented to avoid the branch points.

Comment: I didn't mean to use the term "cross." You can't cross a branch cut.  What I meant to ask is if we're always staying on the original branches.

Comment: So far as I can tell we are.  Think of the branch along the imaginary axis as a branch of $\sqrt{1-z^2}$ between $(-1,1)$.  As long as we stay within those bounds, then, yeah, we are on the original branch.  Again, because we indent the contours, we make sure we are.

Comment: I meant to ask if the second cut was along the negative REAL axis, not the negative imaginary axis.  The direct evaluation of that line integral seems impossible.  How did you get it into such a nice form? Did you bound it first? And I think the it should be a quarter circle indentation.

Comment: I only got a nice form because I made approximations in the limit of $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.  What should be a quarter circle?

Comment: They are quarter circles; note the limit of integration about the branch point at $z=i$.  In any case, I will put more detail into the evaluation of that integral when time allows.

Comment: Nevermind. I'll try to figure it out myself. I'm making a bunch of dumb comments without thinking first.

Comment: Look, just parametrize the integral as I stated and take the limit.  If you need some help, just yell here.

Comment: Parametrizing you get $\displaystyle\int_{C_{i}} f(z) \ dz = i \int_{0}^{\frac{-\pi}{2}} (i+\epsilon e^{i \phi})^{a-1} \Big(i+ \epsilon e^{i \phi} + (i+ \epsilon e^{i \phi})^{-1} \Big)^{b} \epsilon e^{i \phi} d \phi$. What did you do next?

Comment: Taylor expand in $\epsilon$ inside the power of $b$.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos\pars{ax}\cos^{b}\pars{x}\,\dd x:\
     {\large ?}\,,\qquad \pars{~a >\ b\ >\ -1~}}$.

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos\pars{ax}\cos^{b}\pars{x}%
> \,\dd x}
> =\Re\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\expo{\ic ax}\cos^{b}\pars{x}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=\Re
> \int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1 \atop{\vphantom{\Huge A}\verts{{\rm Arg}\pars{z}}\ <\ \pi/2}}
> z^{a}\pars{z^{2} + 1 \over 2z}^{b}\,{\dd z \over \ic z}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 2^{b}}\,\Im\color{#00f}{%
> \int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1 \atop{\vphantom{\Huge A}\verts{{\rm Arg}\pars{z}}\ <\ \pi/2}}
> z^{a - b - 1}\pars{z^{2} + 1}^{b}\,\dd z}\tag{1}
> \end{align}

If we 'close' the arc with the line
$\ds{\braces{\pars{0,y}\ \mid \ -1 \leq y \leq 1}}$ wich include indents 'around'
$\ds{z = \pm\ic}$ and $\ds{z = 0}$, the integral vanishes out. That means that the integral in question is equal to a minus the integral along the above mentioned segment, from $\ds{y = 1}$ t0 $\ds{y = -1}$, with a suitable handling of the indented points. It's summarized in the following expression:
\begin{align}&\color{#00f}{%
\int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1 \atop{\vphantom{\Huge A}\verts{{\rm Arg}\pars{z}}\ <\ \pi/2}}
z^{a - b - 1}\pars{z^{2} + 1}^{b}\,\dd z}
=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\left\lbrace%
-\ \overbrace{\left.\int_{0}^{-\pi/2}z^{a - b - 1}\pars{z^{2} + 1}^{b}\,\dd z\,
\right\vert_{z\ \equiv\ \ic + \epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}}}^{\ds{\large\tt I}}\right.
\\[3mm]&-\ \overbrace{%
\int_{1 - \epsilon}^{\epsilon}y^{a - b - 1}\expo{\ic\pars{a - b - 1}\pi/2}
\pars{-y^{2} + 1}^{b}\ \ic\,\dd y}^{\ds{\large\tt II}}\
-\ \overbrace{\left.\int_{\pi}^{-\pi}z^{a - b - 1}\pars{z^{2} + 1}^{b}\,\dd z\,
\right\vert_{z\ \equiv\ \epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}}}^{\ds{\large\tt III}}
\\[3mm]&-\ \overbrace{\int_{-\epsilon}^{-1 + \epsilon}\pars{-y}^{a - b - 1}
\expo{-\ic\pars{a - b - 1}\pi/2}
\pars{-y^{2} + 1}^{b}\ \ic\,\dd y}^{\ds{\large\tt IV}}
\\[3mm]&\left.-\ \overbrace{%
\left.\int_{\pi/2}^{0}z^{a - b - 1}\pars{z^{2} + 1}^{b}\,\dd z\,
\right\vert_{z\ \equiv\ -\ic + \epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}}}^{\ds{\large\tt V}}
\right\rbrace\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\pars{2}
\end{align}

> Now, we'll check the integral behaviours when $\ds{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}$. Lets examine the integral $\ds{\large\tt I}$:
> \begin{align}
> &\mbox{When}\ \epsilon \to 0^{+}\,,\quad
> \left.\int_{0}^{-\pi/2}z^{a - b - 1}\pars{z^{2} + 1}^{b}\,\dd z\,
> \right\vert_{z\ \equiv\ \ic + \epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}}
> \sim \epsilon^{b + 1} \to 0\quad\mbox{since}\quad b > -1.
> \\[3mm]&\mbox{Similarly, the integral}\ {\large\tt V} \to 0.
> \\[3mm]&\mbox{The integral}\ {\large\tt III}\ \mbox{behaves as}\ \epsilon^{a - b} \to 0\ \mbox{since}\ a > b.
> \\[3mm]&\mbox{Integrals}\ {\large\tt II}\ \mbox{and}\ {\large\tt IV}\
> \mbox{converge when}\ \epsilon \to 0^{+}\ \mbox{since}\ a - b - 1>-1\ \mbox{and}\
> b > -1.
> \end{align}

Then, we are left with $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{see expression}\ \pars{2}~}}$
\begin{align}&\color{#00f}{%
\int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1 \atop{\vphantom{\Huge A}\verts{{\rm Arg}\pars{z}}\ <\ \pi/2}}
z^{a - b - 1}\pars{z^{2} + 1}^{b}\,\dd z}
\\[3mm]&=-\expo{\ic\pars{a - b}\pi/2}\int_{1}^{0}y^{a - b - 1}
\pars{1 - y^{2}}^{b}\,\dd y
+\expo{-\ic\pars{a - b}\pi/2}\int_{0}^{-1}\pars{-y}^{a - b - 1}
\pars{1 - y^{2}}^{b}\,\dd y
\\[3mm]&=\expo{\ic\pars{a - b}\pi/2}\int_{0}^{1}y^{a - b - 1}
\pars{1 - y^{2}}^{b}\,\dd y
-\expo{-\ic\pars{a - b}\pi/2}\int_{0}^{1}y^{a - b - 1}\pars{1 - y^{2}}^{b}\,\dd y
\\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{2\ic\sin\pars{\bracks{a - b}\,{\pi \over 2}}\int_{0}^{1}
y^{a - b - 1}\pars{1 - y^{2}}^{b}\,\dd y}
\end{align}

> Replacing this result in expression $\pars{1}$:
> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos\pars{ax}\cos^{b}\pars{x}
> \,\dd x}
> ={\sin\pars{\bracks{a - b}\pi/2} \over 2^{b - 1}}\,\int_{0}^{1}
> y^{a - b - 1}\pars{1 - y^{2}}^{b}\,\dd y
> \\[3mm]&={\sin\pars{\bracks{a - b}\pi/2} \over 2^{b - 1}}\,\int_{0}^{1}
> y^{\pars{a - b - 1}/2}\pars{1 - y}^{b}\,\half\,y^{-1/2}\,\dd y
> \\[3mm]&={\sin\pars{\bracks{a - b}\pi/2} \over 2^{b}}\,\int_{0}^{1}
> y^{\pars{a - b}/2 - 1}\pars{1 - y}^{b}\,\dd y
> \\[3mm]&={\sin\pars{\bracks{a - b}\pi/2} \over 2^{b}}\,
> {\Gamma\pars{\bracks{a - b}/2}\Gamma\pars{b + 1}\over
> \Gamma\pars{\bracks{a + b}/2 + 1}}
> \end{align}

Here we used the Gamma Function Euler Reflection Identity:
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos\pars{ax}\cos^{b}\pars{x}\,\dd x}
\\[3mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large{\pi \over 2^{b}}\,
{\Gamma\pars{b + 1}\over
\Gamma\pars{1 + \bracks{b + a}/2}\Gamma\pars{1 + \bracks{b - a}/2}}}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks.  I'm aware of that particular evaluation, however. I asked this question 18 months ago when I was having a difficult time understanding branch cuts.

Comment: Technically I asked this question a little less than 17 months ago. :)

Comment: @RandomVariable I found it recently. I'm just one year old in M.SE. When I started to write the answer I was not aware it will be a long answer. It's always a good exercise to integrate along arcs where it is frequently spiced with indents. Thanks.